# Using TeamCity with Appium and Maven throws MalformedUrlException

Tags: teamcity, ui-automation, appium, teamcity-7.1

I'm trying to integrate my UI testing (for iOS app, code in Java, using Appium 0.16) into TeamCity 7.1 for automation, but I get a `MalformedUrlException` on TeamCity build log. It works perfectly from command line (without TeamCity). I'm running Appium on `127.0.0.1` local address and give an appropriate parameter to the WebDriver:

```
http://127.0.0.1/hub/wd
```

I tried several other configurations:

- replacing the local IP with the agent's IP address;
- setting Maven goals (on TeamCity UI) to test, to surefire:test or clean install.

Nothing solves this.